# Histogram on nested group MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following DB Collection of "User" in MongoDB:

```
User
{
    long userId;
    long LastUpdateUtcTimeInTicks;
    Car[] cars;
    ....
}

Car
{
    long carCompany;
    int carModel; // range from 1-10
    int tire1_Pressure // range from 0-40
    int tire2_Pressure // range from 0-40
    int tire3_Pressure // range from 0-40
    int tire4_Pressure // range from 0-40
}
```

Sample of a user

```
[{
  "userId": 1,
    "LastUpdateUtcTime": {
    "$date": "2022-03-14T07:01:22.430Z"
  },
 
  
    "Car": [
      [
        {
          "carCompany": 1201020,
          "carModel": 2,
          "l": 2,
          
          "tire1_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire2_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire3_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire4_Pressure ": 0
        },
        {
          "carCompany": 4204030,
          "carModel": 2,
          "l": 1,
          
          "tire1_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire2_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire3_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire4_Pressure ": 0
        },
        {
          "carCompany": 1201040,
          "carModel": 1,
          "l": 1,
          
          "tire1_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire2_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire3_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire4_Pressure ": 0
        },
        {
          "carCompany": 2202050,
          "carModel": 2,
          "l": 1,
          
          "tire1_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire2_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire3_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire4_Pressure ": 0
        },
        {
          "carCompany": 4304090,
          "carModel": 3,
          "l": 1,
          
          "tire1_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire2_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire3_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire4_Pressure ": 0
        },
        {
          "carCompany": 3203030,
          "carModel": 1,
          "l": 1,
          
          "tire1_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire2_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire3_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire4_Pressure ": 0
        },
        {
          "carCompany": 3203040,
          "carModel": 1,
          "l": 1,
          
          "tire1_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire2_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire3_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire4_Pressure ": 0
        },
        {
          "carCompany": 6306050,
          "carModel": 3,
          "l": 1,
          
          "tire1_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire2_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire3_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire4_Pressure ": 0
        },
        {
          "carCompany": 4204030,
          "carModel": 1,
          "l": 1,
          
          "tire1_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire2_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire3_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire4_Pressure ": 0
        },
        {
          "carCompany": 1201050,
          "carModel": 2,
          "l": 1,
          
          "tire1_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire2_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire3_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire4_Pressure ": 0
        },
        {
          "carCompany": 2202030,
          "carModel": 2,
          "l": 1,
          
          "tire1_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire2_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire3_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire4_Pressure ": 0
        },
        {
          "carCompany": 4204040,
          "carModel": 1,
          "l": 1,
          
          "tire1_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire2_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire3_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire4_Pressure ": 0
        },
        {
          "carCompany": 3203030,
          "carModel": 2,
          "l": 1,
          
          "tire1_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire2_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire3_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire4_Pressure ": 0
        },
        {
          "carCompany": 4204040,
          "carModel": 1,
          "l": 1,
          
          "tire1_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire2_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire3_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire4_Pressure ": 0
        },
        {
          "carCompany": 3202020,
          "carModel": 2,
          "l": 1,
          
          "tire1_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire2_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire3_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire4_Pressure ": 0
        },
        {
          "carCompany": 3202020,
          "carModel": 2,
          "l": 1,
          
          "tire1_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire2_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire3_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire4_Pressure ": 0
        },
        {
          "carCompany": 1301070,
          "carModel": 14,
          "l": 1,
          
          "tire1_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire2_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire3_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire4_Pressure ": 0
        },
        {
          "carCompany": 1301070,
          "carModel": 14,
          "l": 1,
          
          "tire1_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire2_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire3_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire4_Pressure ": 0
        },
        {
          "carCompany": 1301070,
          "carModel": 14,
          "l": 1,
          
          "tire1_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire2_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire3_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire4_Pressure ": 0
        },
        {
          "carCompany": 3303060,
          "carModel": 3,
          "l": 1,
          
          "tire1_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire2_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire3_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire4_Pressure ": 0
        },
        {
          "carCompany": 2302120,
          "carModel": 12,
          "l": 1,
          
          "tire1_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire2_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire3_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire4_Pressure ": 0
        },
        {
          "carCompany": 2302120,
          "carModel": 12,
          "l": 1,
          
          "tire1_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire2_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire3_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire4_Pressure ": 0
        },
        {
          "carCompany": 1301100,
          "carModel": 3,
          "l": 1,
          
          "tire1_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire2_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire3_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire4_Pressure ": 0
        },
        {
          "carCompany": 3203030,
          "carModel": 1,
          "l": 1,
          
          "tire1_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire2_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire3_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire4_Pressure ": 0
        },
        {
          "carCompany": 3203030,
          "carModel": 1,
          "l": 1,
          
          "tire1_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire2_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire3_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire4_Pressure ": 0
        },
        {
          "carCompany": 4204030,
          "carModel": 1,
          "l": 1,
          
          "tire1_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire2_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire3_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire4_Pressure ": 0
        },
        {
          "carCompany": 4204040,
          "carModel": 1,
          "l": 1,
          
          "tire1_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire2_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire3_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire4_Pressure ": 0
        },
        {
          "carCompany": 4204020,
          "carModel": 1,
          "l": 1,
          
          "tire1_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire2_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire3_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire4_Pressure ": 0
        },
        {
          "carCompany": 3303130,
          "carModel": 3,
          "l": 1,
          
          "tire1_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire2_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire3_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire4_Pressure ": 0
        },
        {
          "carCompany": 3303070,
          "carModel": 3,
          "l": 1,
          
          "tire1_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire2_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire3_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire4_Pressure ": 0
        },
        {
          "carCompany": 1201040,
          "carModel": 1,
          "l": 1,
          
          "tire1_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire2_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire3_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire4_Pressure ": 0
        },
        {
          "carCompany": 1201020,
          "carModel": 1,
          "l": 1,
          
          "tire1_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire2_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire3_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire4_Pressure ": 0
        },
        {
          "carCompany": 2202030,
          "carModel": 1,
          "l": 1,
          
          "tire1_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire2_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire3_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire4_Pressure ": 0
        },
        {
          "carCompany": 2202030,
          "carModel": 1,
          "l": 1,
          
          "tire1_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire2_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire3_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire4_Pressure ": 0
        },
        {
          "carCompany": 3202020,
          "carModel": 1,
          "l": 1,
          
          "tire1_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire2_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire3_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire4_Pressure ": 0
        },
        {
          "carCompany": 3202020,
          "carModel": 1,
          "l": 1,
          
          "tire1_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire2_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire3_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire4_Pressure ": 0
        },
        {
          "carCompany": 4204020,
          "carModel": 1,
          "l": 1,
          
          "tire1_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire2_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire3_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire4_Pressure ": 0
        },
        {
          "carCompany": 4204020,
          "carModel": 1,
          "l": 1,
          
          "tire1_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire2_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire3_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire4_Pressure ": 0
        },
        {
          "carCompany": 3203040,
          "carModel": 1,
          "l": 1,
          
          "tire1_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire2_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire3_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire4_Pressure ": 0
        },
        {
          "carCompany": 3203040,
          "carModel": 1,
          "l": 1,
          
          "tire1_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire2_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire3_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire4_Pressure ": 0
        },
        {
          "carCompany": 3203030,
          "carModel": 1,
          "l": 1,
          
          "tire1_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire2_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire3_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire4_Pressure ": 0
        },
        {
          "carCompany": 3203030,
          "carModel": 1,
          "l": 1,
          
          "tire1_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire2_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire3_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire4_Pressure ": 0
        },
        {
          "carCompany": 2202030,
          "carModel": 1,
          "l": 1,
          
          "tire1_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire2_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire3_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire4_Pressure ": 0
        },
        {
          "carCompany": 3202020,
          "carModel": 1,
          "l": 1,
          
          "tire1_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire2_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire3_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire4_Pressure ": 0
        },
        {
          "carCompany": 2202050,
          "carModel": 1,
          "l": 1,
          
          "tire1_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire2_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire3_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire4_Pressure ": 0
        },
        {
          "carCompany": 1201030,
          "carModel": 1,
          "l": 1,
          "tire1_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire2_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire3_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire4_Pressure ": 0
        },
        {
          "carCompany": 4204030,
          "carModel": 1,
          "l": 1,
          "tire1_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire2_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire3_Pressure ": 0,
          "tire4_Pressure ": 0
        }
      ],
    ],
  
  }
  
}]
```

I want to do a histogram of the tires pressure based on the car model and car id, for all users that were updated in the last week (LastUpdateUtcTimeInTicks).
From what I know I need to use "bucketAuto" for the histogram and do an aggregation on the collection but can't figure out the right query to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Give some test data and expected output like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71332809/find-duplicate-and-keep-the-record-with-latest-field-value-in-mongodb)

Comment: Can you give an output sample, why does a 2 normal `$group` stages not suffice?

Comment: because I need a histogram on each of the tires

Comment: Histogram of what, they all have  "tireX_Pressure ": 0...